# How to pass dropdown selected value to next page in smarty

Tags: html, smarty

I am working on smarty website where for the search of the website I am using drop down boxes, text-boxes etc. All is working fine except one drop down box. I am not getting where I am going wrong.
          On home page I have drop down boxes. When you select something & hits submit button then next form opens & here the same dropdown box is there so it should show the selected value (which we selected on the home page). But this is exactly is not happening. Here I am posting my tried code of both forms. Please help me out.
          Only "cmbSidebarRegions" drop down box is not working except that everything is working perfectly. Only "cmbSidebarRegions" value is not showing as selected on form submit.

1) This is a home page

```
               {block name=header}
          <script type="text/javascript" src="{$smarty.const.PATH__JS}/ad.list.js"></script>
      {/block}
      <div id="QuickSearch" class="span-34 last prepend-1 prepend-top append-bottom">
          <div class="span-50 prepend-1 last">
                 <form method="post" action="?module=main&page=ad&action=list"> 
                 <div id="search_home" style="margin-left: 28px;">
                      {assign var="keyword" value=""}
                      {if isset($Keyword)}
                          {assign var="keyword" value=$Keyword}
                      {/if}
                      <input type="text" id="txtKeyword" name="txtKeyword" placeholder="Enter Keywords...." value="{$keyword}" style="width:532px;"/>
                      </div>
                      <div class="search_location" style="margin-top:8px;">
                      <label style="margin-left:6px; margin-right:6px;">in</label>
                      {assign var="Location" value=""}
                      {assign var="LocationID" value="-1"}
                      {assign var="LocationType" value="-1"}
                      {assign var="CityID" value="-1"}
                      {if isset($ObjRegion)}
                          {assign var="Location" value=$ObjRegion->strRegion}
                          {assign var="LocationID" value=$ObjRegion->intID}
                          {assign var="LocationType" value="region"}
                      {/if}
                      {if isset($ObjCity)}
                          {assign var="Location" value=$ObjCity->strCity}
                          {assign var="LocationID" value=$ObjCity->objRegion->intID}
                          {assign var="LocationType" value="city"}
                          {assign var="CityID" value=$ObjCity->intID}
                      {/if}
                      <select id="cmbSidebarRegions" name="cmbSidebarRegions" class="append-bottom" style="width:190px">
                          <option value="-1" selected="selected">All Ireland</option>
                          {foreach from=$Regions item=ObjRegion key=id name=index}
                              <optgroup label="{$ObjRegion->strRegion}">
                                  <option value="?module=main&page=ad&action=list&hdLocationType=region&hdLocationID={$ObjRegion->intID}">All Counties in {$ObjRegion->strRegion}</option>
                                  {foreach from=$ObjRegion->GetCities() item=ObjCity key=id name=index}
                                      {if isset($smarty.get.hdCityID) AND $smarty.get.hdCityID eq $ObjCity->intID}
                                          <option value="?module=main&page=ad&action=list&hdLocationType=city&hdCityID={$ObjCity->intID}" selected="selected">{$ObjCity->strCity}</option>
                                      {else}
                                          <option value="?module=main&page=ad&action=list&hdLocationType=city&hdCityID={$ObjCity->intID}">{$ObjCity->strCity}</option>
                                      {/if}
                                  {/foreach}
                              </optgroup>
                          {/foreach}
                      </select>
                      <input type="hidden" id="hdLocationType" name="hdLocationType" value="{$LocationType}"/>
                      <input type="hidden" id="hdCityID" name="hdCityID" value="{$CityID}"/>
                      <input type="hidden" id="hdLocationID" name="hdLocationID" value="{$LocationID}"/>
                      <!--<input type="text" id="txtLocation" name="txtLocation" placeholder="Location" value="{$Location}"/>-->
                      <label style="margin-left:6px; margin-right:6px;">in</label>
                      {assign var="keywordLocation" value=""}
                      {if isset($KeywordLocation)}
                          {assign var="keywordLocation" value=$KeywordLocation}
                      {/if}
                      <input type="text" id="txtKeywordLocation" name="txtKeywordLocation" placeholder="Location/Area" value="{$keywordLocation}"/>
                      <label style="margin-left:6px; margin-right:6px;">in</label>
                      <span class="selectbox">{include file="blocks/selectbox.tpl" ID="cmbSection" Name="cmbSection" Data=$Sections OptionText="All Sections" label="strSection" value="intID"}</span>
                      <button type="submit">Search</button>
                      </div>
              </form>
          </div>
      </div>
```

2) This is 2nd page

```
    {extends file="theme/master.tpl"}
    {block name=lang}{config_load file="lang.en.conf" section="HOME"}{/block}
    {block name=title}Ads Listing{/block}
    {block name=header}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{$smarty.const.PATH__JS}/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{$smarty.const.PATH__JS}/ad.list.js"></script>
    {/block}
    {block name=SideBar}
        {include file="components/side.bar.tpl"}
    {/block}
    {block name=content}
         <div class="span-36 last">
            <div id="QuickSearch" class="span-34 last prepend-1 prepend-top">
                <div class="span-50 prepend-1 last">
                <div id="search_home" style="margin-left: 28px;">
                    {assign var="keyword" value=""}
                    {if isset($Keyword)}
                        {assign var="keyword" value=$Keyword}
                    {/if}
                    <input type="text" id="txtKeyword" name="txtKeyword" placeholder="Enter Keywords...." value="{$keyword}" style="width:509px;"/>
                    </div>
                    <div id="search_home" style="margin-left: 28px;">
                    {assign var="advertiser" value=""}
                    {if isset($Advertiser)}
                        {assign var="advertiser" value=$Advertiser}
                    {/if}
                    <input type="hidden" id="txtAdvertiser" name="txtAdvertiser" placeholder="Enter advertiser ID...." value="{$advertiser}" style="width:509px;"/>
                    </div>
                <div class="search_location" style="margin-top:8px;">
                    <label style="margin-left:6px; margin-right:6px;">in</label>
                    <select id="cmbSidebarRegions" name="cmbSidebarRegions" class="append-bottom" style="width:161px">
                        <option value="-1" selected="selected">All Ireland</option>
                        {foreach from=$Regions item=ObjRegion key=id name=index}
                            <optgroup label="{$ObjRegion->strRegion}">
                                <option value="?module=main&page=ad&action=list&hdLocationType=region&hdLocationID={$ObjRegion->intID}">All Counties in {$ObjRegion->strRegion}</option>
                                {foreach from=$ObjRegion->GetCities() item=ObjCity key=id name=index}
                                    {if isset($smarty.get.hdCityID) AND $smarty.get.hdCityID eq $ObjCity->intID}
                                        <option value="?module=main&page=ad&action=list&hdLocationType=city&hdCityID={$ObjCity->intID}" selected="selected">{$ObjCity->strCity}</option>
                                    {else}
                                        <option value="?module=main&page=ad&action=list&hdLocationType=city&hdCityID={$ObjCity->intID}">{$ObjCity->strCity}</option>
                                    {/if}
                                {/foreach}
                            </optgroup>
                        {/foreach}
                    </select>

                    <input type="hidden" id="hdLocationType" name="hdLocationType" value="{$LocationType}"/>
                    <input type="hidden" id="hdCityID" name="hdCityID" value="{$CityID}"/>
                    <input type="hidden" id="hdLocationID" name="hdLocationID" value="{$LocationID}"/>
                    <label style="margin-left:6px; margin-right:6px;">in</label>
                    {assign var="keywordLocation" value=""}
                    {if isset($KeywordLocation)}
                        {assign var="keywordLocation" value=$KeywordLocation}
                    {/if}
                    <input type="text" id="txtKeywordLocation" name="txtKeywordLocation" placeholder="Location/Area" value="{$keywordLocation}"/>
                    <label style="margin-left:6px; margin-right:6px;">in</label>
                    {assign var="SectionID" value=-1}
                    {if isset($Section)}
                        {assign var="SectionID" value="{$Section->intID}"}
                        {assign var="valsect" value="{$Section->strSection}"}
                    {/if}
                    {assign var="SubSectionID" value=-1}
                    {if isset($SubSection)}
                        {assign var="SectionID" value="{$SubSection->objSection->intID}"}
                        {assign var="SubSectionID" value="{$SubSection->intID}"}
                        {assign var="valsubsect" value="{$SubSection->strSubSection}"}
                    {/if}
                    <input type="hidden" id="hdSectionID" name="hdSectionID" value="{$SectionID}"/>
                    <input type="hidden" id="hdSubSectionID" name="hdSubSectionID" value="{$SubSectionID}"/>
                    <span class="selectbox">
                        <select id="cmbSectionGroup" name="cmbSectionGroup"  style="width:150px">
                            <option value="-1">All Sections</option>
                            {foreach from=$arrSections item=Section}
                                <optgroup label="{$Section->strSection}">
                                    <option value="section_{$Section->intID}">All Subsections in {$Section->strSection}</option>
                                    {foreach from=$Section->arrSubSections item=SubSection}
                                        <option value="{$SubSection->intID}">{$SubSection->strSubSection}</option>   
                                    {/foreach}   
                                </optgroup>
                            {/foreach}
                        </select>
                    </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="span-32 prepend-1 prepend-top">
                    <hr/>
                </div>
                <div class="span-32 prepend-1 last prepend-top-xxx">
                    <a id="btnSearchOptions" class="ss_sprite ss_bullet_toggle_plus" onclick="ShowSearchOptions()">Show More Search Options</a>
                    <div id="pnlAdvancedSearch" class="hide span-32 prepend-1 last prepend-top-xxx">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="span-32 align-right prepend-top-x">
                    <button onclick="NextPageAds(1)" style="width:90px;cursor:pointer">Search</button>
                    <button onclick="Reset()" style="width:90px;cursor:pointer">Reset</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="midlink">
        <div class="left">
        </div>
        <div class="right">
        <input type="button" value="Send me web feeds for this category" onclick="window.location = '?module=main&page=webfeeds&action=Subscribe'"/>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span-36 last">
            <div id="pnlAds" class="span-34 last prepend-1 append-1 prepend-top append-bottom">
            </div>
        </div>
    {/block}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the "selected" attribute from the first option in the second form:

```
<option value="-1" selected="selected">All Ireland</option>
```

Also notice that you're looking at the hdCityID value to set the current selected item, wich is a hidden field in both forms and never changes (unless you're doing it with javascript):

```
{if isset($smarty.get.hdCityID) AND $smarty.get.hdCityID eq $ObjCity->intID}
```

...

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdCityID" name="hdCityID" value="{$CityID}"/>
```

That means that it doesn't matter what do you select in the cmbSidebarRegions. Better revise your code logic.

Comment: Thanks Borgtex. I have made enough changes in the code & now its working fine. Thanks for your help.